How to create a dynamic SELECT clause with jOOQ
I want to create a select query using JOOQ. I have couple of fields which I want to include or exclude from the query based on a system property value.
In the below method
String getBankDetails(){
return select(field("Name"),
        field("Bank_Account_Name"),
        field("Bank_Account_Number")
        .from(table("BANK"))
        .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED); 
}

I want to add one more field dynamically as illustrated below
field("Bank_Account_Branch") if System.getProperty("enableBranch") == true


Just assign the builder to a variable and then use if?

Use an optional column expression or just project null:
select(
    BANK.NAME,
    BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    "true".equals(System.getProperty("enableBranch"))
        ? BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_BRANCH
        : noField(BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_BRANCH))
.from(BANK)
.fetch();

Alternatively, just project null:
    "true".equals(System.getProperty("enableBranch"))
        ? BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_BRANCH
        : cast(inline(null), BANK.BANK_ACCOUNT_BRANCH))

Please note, this answer assumes you're going to use the code generator. Unless your schema is truly dynamic (and thus not known at compile time), you'll only benefit from using code generation and you'll work around tons of problems. For example, in your question, you didn't attach data types to your projection, so you'll depend on whatever JDBC will return to you. But the answer also works for dynamic schemas:
select(
    field("Name", VARCHAR),
    field("Bank_Account_Name", VARCHAR),
    field("Bank_Account_Number", VARCHAR),
    "true".equals(System.getProperty("enableBranch"))
        ? field("Bank_Account_Branch", VARCHAR)
        : noField(VARCHAR))
.from("BANK")
.fetch();


Thanks!! noField() works well for my case. I had v3.16 jooq so updated it to v3.19 as DSL.noField() was added in v3.17. more info https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2333
